# Assigning a page title to forms created with the form API FAPI

Tags: 7

I have a moule called newsl witch display a page containing a form.
I would like the way to specify the page title.
Is it with drupal_set_title() ? How to call it ?

Answer (score 0):

if your page url http://site.com/my_page

you can use

```
function hook_page_alter(&$page)
{

    if(arg(0)=="my_page")
    {
                 drupal_set_title("Ahmed");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why bother with implementing another hook? Just stick `drupal_set_title()` in the form building function and you're good to go

Comment: if he can do it in form building it will be the best

Comment: Where in form building ?

Comment: Thank you guys. I just call my drupal_set_title () in my form builder